# Error "System.IO.DirectoryNotFound & System.Data.SqlClient "

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am working on a c# .net core console app & sql server, and it works well on my computer. Trying to move it to another env which running windows server. But when I try to start the exe file, it stopped working. The problem details are :

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: 4SPYZEXVPSSBYL2WV2PCSAPXMYYPQTEH
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5f6b3998
  Problem Signature 04: System.Private.CoreLib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.700.20.51601
  Problem Signature 06: df9e4e75
  Problem Signature 07: 451c
  Problem Signature 08: 12
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.DirectoryNotFound
  OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.144.8
  Locale ID: 1036
  Additional Information 1: 4546
  Additional Information 2: 4546de3ba6aa8326a7f344fe5522e4ac
  Additional Information 3: 194d
  Additional Information 4: 194d1bba21b2a38e499fdc93abdceb8a

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: GA5FVQEHAAR2LA10WLGGJSJGVC4UPROF
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5f6b3998
  Problem Signature 04: System.Data.SqlClient
  Problem Signature 05: 4.700.20.37001
  Problem Signature 06: a963fc47
  Problem Signature 07: 97f
  Problem Signature 08: e
  Problem Signature 09: DESLN42EBWMODXJIC4SNFB0CYEHCAGZN
  OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.144.8
  Locale ID: 1036
  Additional Information 1: ed50
  Additional Information 2: ed50b7ce2ebc8a70eb25f302d98c3e70
  Additional Information 3: aee8
  Additional Information 4: aee821223e39821d1428036106827284

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, what can we do? Which version of .NET is it, does the target computer have it installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably created a "framework-dependent" application.

> Applications you create with .NET Core can be published in two
> different modes, and the mode affects how a user runs your app.
>
> Publishing your app as self-contained produces an application that
> includes the .NET Core runtime and libraries, and your application and
> its dependencies. Users of the application can run it on a machine
> that doesn't have the .NET Core runtime installed.
>
> Publishing your app as framework-dependent produces an application
> that includes only your application itself and its dependencies. Users
> of the application have to separately install the .NET Core runtime.

[.NET Core application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-application)